# NSIS NTLM Proxy authentication

Tags: proxy, installation, nsis, ntlm

I'm using NSIS for an installer program. We have to download some package from our server during installation and we use NSISdl library for this.

The problem is that we need to install the software in a network with a proxy with NTLM authentication. As the documentation of NSISdl says (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/NSISdl/ReadMe.txt), it's not possible to use configuration with proxy authentication.

How can I do NTLM authentication? I've found a plugin Inetc for NSIS (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in), it accept proxy authentification, but no indication for NTLM. Does someone have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INetC uses WinINet which is as close to IE as you are probably going to get. [This page](http://pilif.github.com/2004/06/wininet-proxies-and-ntlm/) claims that the `INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION` flag is required for NTLM. I don't know if this plugin uses that flag. If not you could request the author to add it or compile your own version...

Comment: INetC does indeed use INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION.I've tested inetc::get from behind a Microsoft TMG web proxy requiring user authentication (via NTLM): INetC correctly picks-up and uses the proxy.